# How to disable the middle click on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mouse

I can't find where to disable the default Mac OS X behavior of the middle click (opens the dashboard). I have steermouse installed and I would like to use the middle click, the way it was meant to be in a browser, closing or opening new tabs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you settings for Dashboard in Exposé and Spaces Preference Pane?

For Dashboard - change the mouse section to either Nothing (-) or add modifier keys to the mouse click (eg. hold any combination of <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, and or <kbd>Shift</kbd> when choosing what mouse button to use).

[image: Screenshot of Exposé and Spaces]

Comment: On mountainLion you might need to check MissionControl settings.. There is no expose and spaces settings there

Comment: No mention of middle button on Mavericks. Sad.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Same applies to High Sierra!

Answer (score 4):

Watch out for additional preferences that come with your mouse - for instance Logitech Control Centre has a preference for the "wheel button" (middle button to you and I) which maps to mission control by default.

[image: Logitech Control Centre for LS 1 Laser Mouse]